# Mocking void method with EasyMock and Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, easymock

Hello I would like to know what is the best approach to mock void methods for example: I have a PersonManager under the test and then I have dao that is mocked.

```
class PersonManager {

    PersonDao dao...

    PersonManager(PersonDao dao)...

    Preson find(String person)...

    void delete(String person)...

}

class PersonManagerTest {

    Map<String, Person> persons ..... = "person1", "person2", "person3";

    PersonDao mock...

    PersonManager manager = new PersonManager(mock);

    //easy one
    @Test public void shouldReturnExistingPerson() {
        expect(mock.find("person1").andReturn(persons.get(0));
        Person result = manager.find("person1");
        // replay and verify logic
    }

    //but what should I do here?
    @Test public void shouldDeleteExistingPerson() {
        //should I remove a person from testing Map holding test data? or what am I doing wrong
    }
}
```

So testing method with return was easy but how to toset void method? Thank you for suggestions, and Mcokito examples are welcomed too.
        }

Comment: Are any of these answers acceptable for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends entirely on *what* you're trying to test.

In mockito, if you want to check only that the DAO delete method is called with the correct parameter, then [verify](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4) is what you want.

I would suggest that this is exactly what you want since your unit test for `PersonManager` should not be testing `PersonDao`.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 6):

With easy mock, you don't need to wrap void functions around expect(). You just need to do something like:

```
obj = createMock(...)
obj.someVoidMethod();
replay(obj);
...
verify(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

When deleting something, I suggest returning the object you just deleted. It makes testing much, much easier and allows doing things after you deleted (e.g. showing notice, logging, etc). I think most (all?) Java collections are doing so.

Comment: About most / all. All Java collections inherit from the same interface, so if one returns the deleted object, all do.

Comment: This is all true and correct, however very slightly misses the intent of the test (as I understand it). Testing if `PersonManager.delete()` returns a `Person` instance is not the same as testing if it calls `PersonDao.delete()`.

Comment: Again true, but then you're testing if it returns true/false, *not* that the DAO is being called with the correct parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito provides a static `verify` method that can verify when you call any method, even those that have void as return type. For your code sample, the following mockito code should work:

```
// Put this among your import statements    
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*

class PersonManagerTest {

    private PersonManager manager; // SUT

    private Map<String, Person> mockedPersons;

    private PersonDao mockDao;

    // Don't forget to setup from scratch for each test
    @Before public void setup() {
        mockDao = mock(PersonDao.class); // mockito mock method
        mockedPersons = new HashMap<String, Person>();
        for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            mockedPersons.put("person"+i, mock(Person.class));
        }
        manager = new PersonManager(mockDao);
    }

    // setup dao to return a mocked person
    private void whenPersonIsAdded(int i) {
        Person personToReturn = mockedPersons.get("person"+i);
        when(mockDao.find("person"+i)).thenReturn(personToReturn);
    }

    @Test public void shouldReturnExistingPerson() {
        whenPersonIsAdded(1);
        Person expectedPerson = mockPerson;

        Person actualPerson = manager.find("person1");

        assertEquals(expectedPerson, actualPerson);
    }

    @Test public void shouldDeleteExistingPerson() {
        String expectedPersonString = "person1";

        manager.delete(expectedPersonString);

        verify(mockDao).delete(expectedPersonString);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.